# Reduce array of nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic array of nested objects as below:

```
[
    {
        "fields": [
            {
                "field-1": {
                    "id": "field-1",
                    "value": "a1"
                },
                "field-2": {
                    "id": "field-2",
                    "value": "a2"
                },
                "field-3": {
                    "id": "field-3",
                    "value": "a3"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fields": [
            {
                "field-1": {
                    "id": "field-1",
                    "value": "b1"
                },
                "field-2": {
                    "id": "field-2",
                    "value": "b2"
                },
                "field-3": {
                    "id": "field-3",
                    "value": "b3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to parse/reduce this array to below kind of structure:

```
[
    {
        "field-1": "a1",
        "field-2": "a2",
        "field-3": "a3"
    },
    {
        "field-1": "b1",
        "field-2": "b2",
        "field-3": "b3"
    },
]
```

While I already have a verbose way of iterating over the array and constructing the new one, I wanted to know if it is possible to get the structure using the reduce method, as that would be faster?

Comment: If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Oh k...I was not aware of Stacksnippet...However, I just highlighted the input and output format I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version:

```js
const res = data
  .flatMap((obj) => obj.fields)
  .map((obj) =>
    Object.entries(obj).reduce((p, [k, v]) => ({ ...p,
      [k]: v.value
    }), {})
  );

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      "fields": [{
        "field-1": {
          "id": "field-1",
          "value": "a1"
        },
        "field-2": {
          "id": "field-2",
          "value": "a2"
        },
        "field-3": {
          "id": "field-3",
          "value": "a3"
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      "fields": [{
        "field-1": {
          "id": "field-1",
          "value": "b1"
        },
        "field-2": {
          "id": "field-2",
          "value": "b2"
        },
        "field-3": {
          "id": "field-3",
          "value": "b3"
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
</script>
```

### Explanation

We first `flatMap()` the given array since we have array inside array, to get the following:

```
const x = data.flatMap((obj) => obj.fields);
```

Output:

```js
[
    {
        "field-1": {
            "id": "field-1",
            "value": "a1"
        },
        "field-2": {
            "id": "field-2",
            "value": "a2"
        },
        "field-3": {
            "id": "field-3",
            "value": "a3"
        }
    },
    {
        "field-1": {
            "id": "field-1",
            "value": "b1"
        },
        "field-2": {
            "id": "field-2",
            "value": "b2"
        },
        "field-3": {
            "id": "field-3",
            "value": "b3"
        }
    }
]
```

Now for each object in the above array, I just need to change the value of each key in each object. So we need to call `map` on the previous output and for each object, generate our desired object using `reduce()`:

```js
const res = x.map((obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((p, [k, v]) => ({ ...p, [k]: v.value }), {}))
```

Output:

```js
[
    {
        "field-1": "a1",
        "field-2": "a2",
        "field-3": "a3"
    },
    {
        "field-1": "b1",
        "field-2": "b2",
        "field-3": "b3"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor and perhaps not repeat yourself. You are mapping twice. That is not necessary

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer to include working snippet editor. Yes, In my approach I am mapping twice. If single loop version is needed there is another answer too :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use reduce to do it

```js
const result = raw
  .map(row => Object.entries(row.fields[0])
    .reduce((acc, [key, { value }]) => {
       acc[key] = value
       return acc
    }, {})
  )

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script>
  const raw = [{
      "fields": [{
        "field-1": {
          "id": "field-1",
          "value": "a1"
        },
        "field-2": {
          "id": "field-2",
          "value": "a2"
        },
        "field-3": {
          "id": "field-3",
          "value": "a3"
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      "fields": [{
        "field-1": {
          "id": "field-1",
          "value": "b1"
        },
        "field-2": {
          "id": "field-2",
          "value": "b2"
        },
        "field-3": {
          "id": "field-3",
          "value": "b3"
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...This structure is perfect...Just one last question though...In case, I do not want to keep any references (so kind of deep copying), can I achieve that as well ?

Comment: I think that is deep copying because string is not a reference.

Answer (score 3):

You Can try this code

```js
var convert=[];
for (let i=0; i< test.length; i++){
    var obj={};
    Object.entries(test[i]).forEach(entry => { 
        const [key, value] = entry; 
        for(let j=0; j < value.length; j++){
            Object.entries(value[j]).forEach(s => { var [ k,v ] = s; obj[k]= v.value  }); 
        }
    })
    convert[i]=obj
}
console.log(convert);
```

```html
<script>
var test=[
    {
        "fields": [
            {
                "field-1": {
                    "id": "field-1",
                    "value": "a1"
                },
                "field-2": {
                    "id": "field-2",
                    "value": "a2"
                },
                "field-3": {
                    "id": "field-3",
                    "value": "a3"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fields": [
            {
                "field-1": {
                    "id": "field-1",
                    "value": "b1"
                },
                "field-2": {
                    "id": "field-2",
                    "value": "b2"
                },
                "field-3": {
                    "id": "field-3",
                    "value": "b3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...This structure is perfect...Just one last question though...In case, I do not want to keep any references (so kind of deep copying), can I achieve that as well ?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that as well.

Comment: Ok..I was wondering if spread would help here, since it is a nested structure...

Answer (score 2):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) can be used to modify nested values :

```js
const data = [{"fields":[{"field-1":{"id":"field-1","value":"a1"},
                          "field-2":{"id":"field-2","value":"a2"},
                          "field-3":{"id":"field-3","value":"a3"}}]},
              {"fields":[{"field-1":{"id":"field-1","value":"b1"},
                          "field-2":{"id":"field-2","value":"b2"},
                          "field-3":{"id":"field-3","value":"b3"}}]}]

let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), (k, v) => v.value ?? v.fields?.[0] ?? v)

console.log( result )
```